# Has someone been defenestrated?

Tags: code-golf, string

> **Defenestration** is the act of throwing someone or something out of a window.
>   <sub>—[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestration)</sub>

### Input

The input will consist of two parts:

- A floor plan and a person inside the house/building.

  - `v><^` represents a person, pointing in the direction signified by the arrow. The input will contain exactly one person.
  - `-` and `|` represent walls, and `#` represents a window.   is empty space.

  This portion of the input may be taken as either a single string, or an array/list/etc. of lines. There will never be any trailing or leading spaces, and the input will always be a rectangle.

  Example:

  ```
  -----###---
  |         |
  |     ^   |
  -----------
  ```
- An integer ≥ 1 signifying how far (in characters) the person travels.

### Output

The output should be

- `1` if the person ends up "inside" a window (i.e. after moving forwards the distance specified in the input, the person is on top of a `#`).
- `2` if the person has been defenestrated (come into contact with a `#` and then continued further on).
- `3` if the person has hit a wall (come into contact with a `-` or `|`. Once hitting the wall, the person stops and does not continue through it).
- `0` if none of the above are true (and all the person has done is travel through empty space).

### Assumptions

All of the following can be assumed to be true:

- The person will never travel "out of bounds" of the input area.
- After being defenestrated, the person will never come into contact with another `#` or a `-`/`|` (so you don't have to worry about if `2` *and* `1` or `3` are both true).

### Test cases

For the following "floor plan":

```
-----
|   |
|###|
|   |
| ^ |
```

```
In   Out
1    0
2    1
3    2
```

For this floor plan:

```
> | # |
```

```
In   Out
1    0
2-99 3    * that is, any input 2-99 outputs 3
```

For this floor plan:

```
||####|#|#|##|<
```

```
In   Out
any  3
```

Final test case:

```
|v|
|#|
| |
| |
| |
| |
```

```
In   Out
1    1
2-5  2
```

Comment: I propose the title of this challenge be changed to [Defenestration testing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_testing)

Comment: Follow-up question: This, except with pit's.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ `Has someone been for-sparta'd?`

Comment: Why did my edit get rejected ):

Comment: @cat Because it's an edit on someone else's question, that they must have input on.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I thought it was up to 1k+ users too, but it was just a title change

Comment: Can we assume that the input is left-and-right-padded with spaces to form a rectangle?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ "*There will never be any trailing or leading spaces.*" Yes, the input will always be a rectangle (editing that in).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>147</s> 146 bytes

```js
(p,n)=>eval('l=p.search`\n`+1;m=p.match`[<>v^]`;for(r=d=i=0;i++<n&r<3;r-1?0:d=2)r=(c=p[m.index+i*({v:l,"<":-1,">":1}[m]||-l)])>"#"?3:c>" ";+r||d')
```

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@NinjaBearMonkey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29750/ninjabearmonkey)!*

### Explanation

Takes a floorplan as a string and the number of moves. Returns a number.

```js
(p,n)=>                               // p = floor plan as string, n = number of moves
  eval(`                              // use eval to enable for loop without {} or return
    l=p.search\`\n\`+1;               // l = line length
    m=p.match\`[<>v^]\`;              // m = the position and orientation of the person
    for(
      r=                              // r = result at the current step
        d=                            // d = 2 if the person has been defenestrated
          i=0;                        // i = current step
      i++<n&r<3;                      // for each step while the person has not hit a wall
      r-1?0:d=2                       // set d to 2 once the person enters the window
    )
      r=(                             // r = 0 if on " ", 1 if on "#" or 3 if on "|" or "-"
        c=p[m.index+i*                // c = character after current step
          ({v:l,"<":-1,">":1}[m]||-l) // get the index offset of each step
        ]
      )>"#"?3:c>" ";
    +r||d                             // return the result of the current step or d
  `)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = (p,n)=>eval('l=p.search`\n`+1;m=p.match`[<>v^]`;for(r=d=i=0;i++<n&r<3;r-1?0:d=2)r=(c=p[m.index+i*({v:l,"<":-1,">":1}[m]||-l)])>"#"?3:c>" ";+r||d')
```

```html
<textarea id="floorplan" rows="6" cols="30">-----
|   |
|###|
|   |
| ^ |</textarea><br />
Moves = <input type="text" id="moves" value="3" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(floorplan.value,moves.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I like your testing snippet!

Comment: ಠ_ಠ I was just about to post pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Haha, I know that feeling all too well...

Comment: Nice answer, btw! Very smart.

Comment: You can save two bytes by making it a curried function and using a regular function - `p=>n=>{l=p.search\`\n\`+1;m=p.match\`[<>v^]\`;for(r=d=i=0;i++<n&r<3;r-1?0:d=2)r=(c=p[m.index+i*({v:l,"<":-1,">":1}[m]||-l)])>"#"?3:c>" ";return+r||d}`